# How do I compute derivative of a lambda expression using Sympy?

Tags: python, sympy, derivative

How to compute a lambda expression's derivative ?

For example:

```
func = lambda x: x ** 3 - 3 * x ** 2
...
# the code
...
derived_func = lambda x: 3 * x ** 2 - 6 * x
```

Comment: This is a `sympy` task, not a `numpy` one.  Don't try to mix the two casually.

Comment: I asked a question due to lack of knowledge on the specific subject. This is what SOF was made for. No need to comment for the comment.

Comment: @LiorElisberg It's important to tag correctly. Users who see unrelated questions due to the tag filter they use might downvote for using the wrong tag. It's best to [edit] your question to remove the wrong tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the lambda with a symbol as a parameter, and then differentiate the resulting expression:

```py
from sympy import *
x = symbols('x')
func = lambda x: x ** 3 - 3 * x ** 2
display(func(x).diff(x))
```

Result: `3*x**2 - 6*x`

Comment: Is display() a function of sympy?

Comment: @LiorElisberg ah, `display(..)` is from [Jupyter](https://jupyter.org/) but `print(..)` works here just as well and doesn't depend on Jupyter.